# load page at its hash, then display the result directly without showing the index first

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, hash

on http://zentili.koding.com i've got this javascript that loads the content of the linked menu item inside the main #content div of the index page, and applies an hash with the name of the loaded page minus the '.php', otherwise it loads the hash + '.php' if it's entered in the url. works very good. On other hand, the ENG/ITA entries add ?locale=lang_LANG inside the url, right before the hash, so that localization is also working fine. If you look well, you may notice that when you switch between ENG and ITA, the index-content appears just for one moment before going to the hash. I know this is because the page is first loaded, then taken to the hash but i was wondering if there some way for hiding the homepage and going directly to the hash location when it's loaded.

Here the code for my menu:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {  
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);  
var href = $('#menubar a.item').each(function(){  
var href = $(this).attr('href');  
if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-4)){  
    var toLoad = hash+'.php';  
    $('#content').load(toLoad);  
    $("#menubar a.item").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
}  
});

$('#menubar a.item').click(function(){  
window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-4); 
var toLoad = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').fadeOut('fast',loadContent);  
    function loadContent() {  
    $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent)  }  
    function showNewContent() {  
    $('#content').fadeIn('fast');  }
    $("#menubar a.item").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");

    return false; 
});

});

function goENG(){
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var eng = '?locale=en_EN';
        window.location.replace(eng+hash) ;
};

function goITA(){
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var ita = '?locale=it_IT';
        window.location.replace(ita+hash) ; 
};

</script>
```

the functions goENG() and goITA() are called via onclick on the ENG and ITA a's. I hope to find some solution into this.

Answer (score 0):

The page cannot directly go to the link. It will load in its natural order and then it will go to the hash. For what you want to achieve, there is a simple solution i believe.

1. Hide the main content div until the document loads. use css rule "**visibility:hidden**" for this
2. If there is any hash, load it and then make the content visible.
3. If there is no hash in url, make the content visible on dom load.

   ```
      $(document).ready(function() {  
           var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);  
           if ($('#menubar a.item').length > 0) { 
               var href = $('#menubar a.item').each(function(){  
                   var href = $(this).attr('href');  
                   if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-4)){  
                       var toLoad = hash+'.php';  
                       $('#content').load(toLoad, function(){
                           $('#content').attr('visibility', 'visible');
                       });  

                       $("#menubar a.item").removeClass("current");
                       $(this).addClass("current");
                   } else {
                       $('#content').attr('visibility', 'visible');                    
                   }  
               });
           } else {
               $('#content').attr('visibility', 'visible');
           }
       });
   ```

--UPDATE--

If you are setting #content as "visibility:hidden"

```
$('#content').attr('visibility', 'visible');
```

should always fire, else your #content div will be invisible. The trick here is to set it to visible after we are done with checking for hash. You can keep loading the content in the div and make it visible. Making the #content div visible need not be done after entirely loading the hash.

Comment: how do i actually "load" the hash in background? adding   `$(document).ready(function(){
    if (window.location.hash){
    $('#content').attr('visibility', 'visible');
    };
    
});` on with `visibility:hidden;` into #content doesn't show the content at all!

Comment: I have updated the answer above. You need to do the visibility:hidden in css ans do visibility as visible in the js after checking the hash and loading the DOM

Comment: i've already got `visibility:hidden` into css under `#content`. adding   `if (window.location.hash){$("#content").attr("visibility", "visible");};` to the `$(document).ready` function doesnt show the content!

Comment: Why are you adding $("#content").attr("visibility", "visible"); in the if (window.location.hash) ?? It should not be in that if condition see the code in answer above. It is placed directly in the document.ready function

Comment: putting it into the $(document).ready function and changin it to $('#content').css('visibility', 'visible'); is showing the content, but the home page still appears before. i think we need something like "when the page is taken to the hash, then display the content."